# Swap or hook an ally being lassoed by Batrider

Tags: dota-2, dota

Can I save my ally being dragged away by *Batrider's lasso* by hooking or swapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

- Hook will just hit the target and return without the unit.

  (watch 1:15)
- Swap will put vengeful spirit on the targeted position,but it won't move away the targeted hero.

  (watch 9:54 ,from dota 1 but still the same)

However if you are in good position,you can hook/swap batrider,preventing him from dragging you ally away.

Comment: Nice find. So the key for saving your ally when being dragged is to  swap batrider instead. But isn't hooking batrider will make your ally suffer more since he's still being dragged by batrider and worse suffer from those flaming grounds batrider leaves on the ground.

Comment: That's why you need to be in good position,usually you will just move batrider back and your ally will stay in place...even on max distance you will drag your ally just a little bit,which might go in your favor since the worst part is if batrider separates your teammate from your group.